# Permission denied error installing Pillow (PIL) on mac

Tags: python, macos, python-imaging-library

I'm attempting to install the Pillow fork of PIL, and every method I've tried results in this error:

> unable to execute /: Permission denied
>
> error: command '/' failed with exit status 1

This occurs

1. using `pip install Pillow`
2. using `easy_install Pillow-master.zip`
3. using `python setup.py install`
4. using `python setup.py build`

The last is the most confusing to me, honestly. I can't even build the module in the same directory it's been extracted to.

I've made sure to install all of the prereqs using homebrew, just as the Pillow readme suggests.

This error has not occurred when installing other python modules.

Edit: I have run all of these commands with and without sudo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've solved the problem by now.  If you haven't, you can now install pillow using brew by going

`brew install samueljohn/python/pillow`.

Why it isn't `just brew install pillow` is beyond me.

Answer (score 1):

I am a newbie, I tried everything you did for the last 24 hours... Then I did the following

1. I installed Xcode and then installed Command line tools (Go to Xcode preference menu, click on downloads, select and install command line).
2. I then installed brew  (I had been using macports and I kept getting some permission errors)
3. this is the surprising bit.. I then tried using:

   easy_install pillow

and it worked, no more errors... I have no idea if step 1 and 2 above had anything to do with step 3 working, or its because I stopped trying to install PIL and instead went for pillow but its now working.

So what am I saying, try using easy_install pillow read more about pillow here (http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/how-to-use-pillow/)

Good luck, let me know if it works.. if anyone has any idea why mine worked as well, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Jan 2021  Mac OS Big Sur 11.1  brew install samueljohn fails ...

```
brew install samueljohn/python/pillow
==> Tapping samueljohn/python
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/samueljohn/homebrew-python'...
remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/samueljohn/homebrew-python/'
Error: Failure while executing; `git clone https://github.com/samueljohn/homebrew-python /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/samueljohn/homebrew-python` exited with 128.
```

Comment: Please explain how this solves the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

It look like you have activated your virtual environment, in such case you have to run the following cmd

```
sudo python -m pip install Pillow
```